# having problems with installing composer

Tags: composer-php

I'm having problems installing composer. The error being displayed is:

> Connection Error [ERR_CONNECTION]: Unable to connect to getcomposer.org
>   Proxy http####://10.50.7.154:3128### [from Internet Settings] failed with errors:
>   Failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>
> Request to https://getcomposer.org/installer failed with errors:
>   Failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: What command did you use? What operating system are you using?

Comment: php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));" the command l used

Comment: Try using the command as described in [the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#manual-installation): `php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php`

Answer (score 1):

That's a proxy problem, right there. Please step away from the building you are in and find a regular coffeeshop with regular broadband WiFi.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Please step away from the building you are in", i'm sorry but that cracked me up :P